# Custom hashCode when using part of a List for comparision

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I am trying to write a custom hashCode fn, but I am not able to figure out the correct way to do that.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    List<String> attributes;

    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Persons are equal if name is equal & if >= 2 of attributes are equal
        // This I have implemented
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 59;
        int result = 1;
        result = (result*PRIME) + (this.name == null ? 0 : this.name.hashCode());

        //Not sure what to do here to account for attributes            

        return result;
    }
}
```

I want the hashCode fn to be such that:
"If object1 and object2 are equal according to their equals() method, they must also have the same hash code"

Not sure how to do that?

Comment: Your equals definition is not transitive, and is therefore invalid. You can have a==b, and b==c, but not a==c.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for the reply. Yes, you are right. How should I handle this case then? I basically have a List<Person> & I want to remove the duplicates, based on the above criteria.

Comment: My idea was to Override the hashCode & equals fn & then transform the List to a Set, to remove duplicates

Comment: The problem is that because you don't have transitivity, you don't have a coherent definition of "duplicate".  In my a, b, c example, which ones should be removed?

Comment: In case it's not clear from @OliCharlesworth's excellent comment, imagine if `a`, `b` and `c` have attributes `[1,2,3]`, [`2,3,4`] and `[3,4,5]`. Which are duplicates?

Comment: Got your point. Considering the list to be sorted & that priority(a) > priority(b) > priority(c). b should be removed. So first I keep a, now b should be removed, since it is similar to a, now c can be retained as a & c are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Oli points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322859/custom-hashcode-when-using-part-of-a-list-for-comparision#comment39474007_25322859), you cannot solve this by implementing `equals()` and relying on a `Set` to de-duplicate for you. Weird things could happen.

Thus you must resort to coding this yourself. Add the first item from your list into your new de-duplicated list. Then for each remaining item in your original list, compare it with those already present in your de-duplicated list and only add it if it passes your non-duplicate test.

Comment: Thanks!. Looks like that is the only option I have here.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to fulfill the contract of the equals/hashcCode methods is to return a constant:
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {return 13;}

Otherwise your solution with a hash code based only on name will work.

Comment: This won't resolve the underlying problem of a non-transitive equals method.

Comment: No, but it will answer the question about how to implement a hashCode method fulfilling the equals/hashCode contract.